# Open a web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, tabcontrol

I have created two buttons close and new tab and a web browser which loads google. When I click new tab it opens the new tab but doesn't open a web browser.
Here's the code I have so far which is from the Microsoft help site. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with c#.

```
private void newTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}

private void closeTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}
```

At the moment I have this code but when I type in the search box it only works in tabpage 1
and not in any of the new tabs that I open so I need to add some code to the searchbox?

my code is:

```
private void newTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);


    var browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    browser.Url = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com");


    myTabPage.Controls.Add(browser);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add a new instance of the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.webbrowser.aspx) control to your tab:

```
private void newTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);

    // Create new WebBrowser instance
    var browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    browser.Url = new Uri(@"http://www.google.de");

    // Add the WebBrowser control to the TabPage.
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(browser);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}
```

Each `TabPage` is initially empty, just like it is if you would have added it using the designer. It's content depends on what you want to add. Sharing a `WebBrowser`-Control does not make sense, since you want to open different websites on different tabs, I guess.

In case you do not want the user to close the first tab you can simply check if the tab the user requests to close is the first one created:

```
private void closeTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Is the Tab Page the first one?
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages[0])
        return;

    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}
```

Or in case you want **at least one** tab page to stay "open" you can use the [`TabCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabcount.aspx)-Property:

```
private void closeTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Is the Tab Page the last one opened?
    if (tabControl1.TabCount == 1)
        return;

    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}
```

Comment: works perfectly thank you also is there a way the user cant close the first tab

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [webbrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control in your code:

```
private void newTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        myTabPage.Controls.Add(wb);
        wb.Navigate("google.com");
}

private void closeTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(tabControl1.TabPages.Count == 1)
       return;

    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}
```

Comment: this works but the webbrowser is really small in the corner of the form and needs to be anchored also is there a way for the user not to delete the last tab so that its always there

Comment: that works perfectly thank you, is having google or the website name in the tab more advanced and difficult to do?

Comment: @user1934845 not difficult, set myTabPage.Text to whatever you want

Comment: iv got the first tab saying google but then when i browse a website it's not going to change

Comment: @user1934845 you must handle webbroser's navigated event and set myTabPage.Text from where. But search how to do that by yourself, it's not difficult :)